# Remove primary x axis and keep only duplicated secondary axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is silly. But how I can remove the x axis on the bottom of a ggplot and keep only the secondary axis?

```
foo <- tibble(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

EDIT: Thanks to the comments...solved.

```
ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(position ="top")
```

Comment: Try using `scale_x_continuous(position = "top")`

Comment: Any reason why you can't just move the axis from the bottom to the top instead of using a secondary axis?

Comment: Right...I didn't know about the position = "top" argument. Told you it was a silly question!

Answer (score 1):

You could set axis.x.bottom parameters in theme. Try:

```
foo <- tibble(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x.bottom = element_blank(), axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing. I didn't know about the position="top" option. Thanks.

```
foo <- tibble(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(foo,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(position ="top")
```